# HTML to PDF/rtf/doc/etc converters?

Tags: html, pdf, rtf, doc

We are looking for a server-side solution that is capable of taking an HTML page and generating a document in one of several formats - pdf, as well as rtf, doc, etc.

I've used LiveDocX to mail-merge elements using a Word Doc template and generate pdf's with success.  I also know that it is capable supporting our requirement of generating other formats in addition to pdf.  But I am not sure if I can supply an HTML page and generate these files?

I see there is a gamut of HTML to PDF converter options.  I've seen the the list posted up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178448/list-of-html-to-pdf-converters.  But what I am looking for is additional capability to generate not just pdf's but multiple formats.

A server-side Microsoft IIS (.NET or COM+) solution is preferred, but will also look at good PHP options.

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

What about some funky OpenOffice skripts, that transform given HTML page. It should be flexible enough.